# How to execute another task if current task takes too much time in python

Tags: python, time

I have some function to execute which might take longer time.

What i want to do is if the given function is taking more than 5 second then terminate this task and execute some another function.

```
if (function(a) > 5 seconds)
    function(b)
else
    function(c)
```

Comment: Thanks. Its exactly the same i am looking for.

Comment: I would scroll down to (or Cmd-F for) the `ProcessPoolExecutor` solution. If it does what you want, it's much shorter and simpler than the other answers, including the accepted one (and portable to Windows, too).